# number of views in search results - call out for aspx page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, enterprise-search

whats the meaning of num of views=3 for an `aspx page`, thats coming in from the search results page? am confused about this.
this num of views 3  is not appearing for other pages. for some pages it displays the nu of views and for some  it didnt.
Whats the  criteria , the search engine displays these results / `num of views`?

this is happening only for the document type `webpage` NOT for documents, xls, pptx or pdf files

[image: numof-viewsin-callout-srch-results]

Comment: Its showing the values at my end. The document needs to viewed couple of times i guess for the `Viewslifetime` property to be filled. If the document is not viewed then i guess the value wont be displayed.

Comment: is there any workaround, like i can hide it permanently ? or can i display these numbers for all the pages?

Comment: you can use css to hide it permanently.